# Error: Call to a member function viewVars() on array on CakePHP

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I am trying to send an email with cakephp.
My setup code is below. It doesn't matter if I switch the config in for gmail or fast, or add viewVars to the other email settings - I get this error:

```
Call to a member function viewVars() on array
```

If I cut out viewVars line from the new CakeEmail() block - it gives me

```
 Call to a member function send() on array
```

Which makes me think there's something wrong with my settings somewhere?

I have the email set up in the controller like this:

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
            $email->template('remember_password', 'default')
                    ->config('default')
                    ->emailFormat('html')
                    ->subject(__('Remember password - ' . Configure::read('Application.name')))
                    ->to($user['User']['email'])
                    ->from(Configure::read('Application.from_email'))
                    ->viewVars(array('hash' => $hash))
                    ->send();
```

Settings are like this:

```
class EmailConfig {

  public $default = array(
    'transport' => 'Mail',
    'from' => 'myemail@email.com',
    //'charset' => 'utf-8',
    //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );

  public $smtp = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('myemail@email.com' => 'My Site'),
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 25,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => false,
    //'charset' => 'utf-8',
    //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );

  public $gmail = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'myemail@email.com',
    'password' => 'password',
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    );

  public $fast = array(
    'from' => 'myemail@email.com',
    'sender' => null,
    'to' => null,
    'cc' => null,
    'bcc' => null,
    'replyTo' => null,
    'readReceipt' => null,
    'returnPath' => null,
    'messageId' => true,
    'subject' => null,
    'message' => null,
    'headers' => null,
    'viewRender' => null,
    'template' => false,
    'layout' => false,
    'viewVars' => null,
    'attachments' => null,
    'emailFormat' => null,
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 25,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => true,
    //'charset' => 'utf-8',
    //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );
```

Comment: I had similarly problem @itamar. Try to include `compact()`function inside your viewVars like this and rum your ode again: `->viewVars(compact('hash'));`. CakePHP will understand that $hash variable belongs to `'hash'`quoted inside this function to pass through your view

Comment: @bcesars that was a good guess but ndms answer solved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Application.from_email` does not exist or is `null`, causing `CakeEmail::from()` to receive `null` as an argument, resulting in it acting as a getter, ie it will return the current `from` value, which is an array, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks - this was the answer!

Comment: after trying everything and ignoring this reply at the start, i read this reply carefully which solved my problem, thank you @ndm